# Download the file from a certain point

Tags: c#

I want to download file from URL (like video). I know how to do it using WebClient, but now I want to start download from some point of this file (for example from half) as far as I know it is impossible to do it using WebClient. So how can I do it?

Comment: HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if server supports byte range

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var bytesToSkip = 100_000;
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("file to download"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        Headers = { Range = new RangeHeaderValue(bytesToSkip, null)}
    };

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}
```